# Give alias to query result

Tags: sql, ms-access, alias

Let's take this piece of code as example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Players.Team, AVG(Players.BirthDate) AS AvgBirthDate
      FROM Players
      GROUP BY Players.Team)
WHERE AvgBirthDate = (SELECT MAX(AvgBirthDate)
                      FROM (SELECT Players.Team, AVG(Players.BirthDate) AS AvgBirthDate
                            FROM Players
                            GROUP BY Players.Team))
```

My question is if there is a way to give an alias to the whole query result so that something like this would be possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Players.Team, AVG(Players.BirthDate) AS AvgBirthDate
      FROM Players
      GROUP BY Players.Team) AS QueryResult
WHERE AvgBirthDate = (SELECT MAX(AvgBirthDate)
                      FROM QueryResult)
```

[URL to the code/db](http://www.itcgfermi.org/query/kxyz.aspx)

Comment: You could use a WITH clause/cte instead.

Comment: That looks a little inneficient, you could do that in a single query using a window'd aggregate

Comment: the first question to ask is which mysql version are you using ? mysql 5.x the answer is no, with mysql 8.x see the comments before

Comment: Additionally, what is the data type of `Birthdate` - you cannot perform an average aggregation on a *date*...?

Comment: @nbk I don't really know which version I'm using because it's one of my school personal sites, you just search it and code, www.itcgfermi.org/query is the url, maybe you know how to figure it out

Comment: @Stu It's datetime, you can perform AVG it just gives a weird result that idk what it means  but my teacher said to use it :/, looks weird to me aswell

Comment: so what is the average of 2022-01-01 + 2021-05-21?

Comment: @Stu i guess it's the average of the total of days from 0000-01-01 (?) I can't try that because my school site has premade tables and ican't create more withnew data, i performed AVG to find the average birthdate of a team's players and it works :/

Comment: Ok I stand corrected about taking the average of dates, MySql will do it, so the [average of those two dates above](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=708620e6dee8ad1b62e835aa1f9d9bfb) is `2021-53-11`. Make of that what you will....

Comment: Do `select version()` to get the version

Comment: I have the feeling your teacher wanted you to get average age, not average birthdate

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems to be a Microsoft Access database.

Comment: Besides, OP doesn't seem to have a problem with their query because if this is a MySQL query, I'm pretty sure they will receive `Every derived table must have its own alias` error message. I'm removing the MySQL tag.

Comment: @FanoFN Yes, I asked my teacher and he said it's a microsoft access database. The original query works (the one I showed is a simplified one), I was just wondering if it could be possible to create an alias for that and it looks like a WITH clause is what I need. The URL you added to the questions didn't seem to work for me, I edited it and looks like it does now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use With clause. If it's not possible, you should consider using a view or a temporary table to store the result of a query that might be use several times after its execution.

Comment: Some systems that process sql queries have a cache mechanism that prevents the execution of the same query many times in a row.